# how to install a program on a USB

Tags: raspbian

I was installing a program on my Raspberry Pi,

but there was no more space on my SD-card.

is it possible to install it on an external USB-stick, plugged into the PI?

Comment: This may solve the immediate problem but if you are running out of space on the SD card you will have continued problems as logs etc. use the remaining space. In the long run you would be better off solving the root cause rather than the side effects.

Answer (score 1):

If the program uses an installation script, it may have a parameter to specify the install location.   If it's a program that you install by copying to (for example) /usr/bin, you can simply copy it to your USB drive.

To run the program, you can either add the USB drive to your PATH, or simply type the full path of the program to launch it (/path/to/usb/programname)

If the program is installed via a package (apt-get...), it will be tougher.

Comment: it's an installation with apt-get. do I have to put everything on the USB now? or is there an other way?

Answer (score 1):

`apt` generally installs programs in `/usr/bin`, and moving individual files elsewhere will sooner or later break your system. Programs which define paths at compile time may simply stop working if you move them to a different folder.

It is possible to move your entire `/usr/bin` or even the root partition to a USB drive, but I'd try less drastic options first. Consider that if something happens with the drive hosting `/usr/bin` and it fails to mount, you won't be able to boot your system normally anymore.

If you have significant user data on the SD card (big files inside your home directory) or a big swap file, those would be the first candidates to relocate to a USB drive. Then you should consider relocating any software you install yourself, without `apt`. Whatever you install with `make install` can be easily relocated from `/usr/local/bin` with `./configure --prefix=/path/to/install/dir` or a similar command. Software installed from archives can often be extracted to a directory of your choice. If you host a web server, the web root can be easily moved from `/var/www` as well.

Make sure you only relocate stuff which actually takes space. `du -c .` is a handy command which calculates the total size of sub-directories of your current path recursively. In the end, if most of your SD card is occupied by system directories, the best course of action is to get a bigger card.