# Storing Database or installing program on USB drive

Tags: python, sqlite, pi-b

I am planning to use by old Raspberry Pi Model B for webscraping with a python script. The data stored will eventually get huge (in GBs). So my SD card will run out quickly. I have a larger capacity USB thumb drive which I plan to use. This is easy if the data is stored in CSV format but because of the data size I would like to use a DB like SQLite. Is there a way to use SQLite on the Pi and store the data on the thumb drive?

I did read a lot on this forum and elsewhere about this and how writing to a USB drive is not recommended as it will exhaust the write cycles; nonetheless.

I found this(to keep my hopes up), the OP has done something to this end: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=143284

Also, I found this: [how to install a program on a USB](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19856/how-to-install-a-program-on-a-usb)

Will installing SQLite on the USB drive mean it will store the data on the drive in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the sqlite data files wherever you want.  The data files do not have to be on the same device as the executable.

Perhaps look at https://sqlite.org/index.html